# How do we get back 12 months date form current date

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel

If ***Current date*** is to day **(02-06-2015)**,
   then how do we get the  **date  back from  12 months**  . 
   so that i get one ***year info***

Comment: What you have tried so far ??

Answer (score 1):

To get date of last year

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . "-1 Year"));
```

Comment: Apologize for missing - in -1 year